# Add Google Maps Layer to OpenLayers Page

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

```
<script src="openlayers.js"></script>    
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
....
  var google = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
            "Google Streets", // the default
            {numZoomLevels: 20}
        );
....
   map.addLayers([
      main_layer,
      google
   ]);
....
</script>
```

Before adding the Google Maps Layer like this, everything worked. Now I get an `TypeError: google.maps is undefined`.  What is wrong?

---

Please tell me if I totally misunderstood the concept of adding a google maps layer to openlayers

Comment: Looks like you are importing google maps api, which you don't need, and not open layers, which you do

Comment: I DO import open layers as well, and even if I ommit the line `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>`, I still get the same error.

Comment: Which version of Ol are you using. I mean 2.x.x not 2 or 3. Sometimes the function defs change.

Comment: I am using OpenLayers 2.14

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The problem is the variable 'google', which overwrites something as it can be imagined.

I call it 'google_layer', now it works - no, it still does not work but at least it does not bring any JS error.

Comment: ah great, i couldnt work it out either, but now i see its obvious, i was using a variable named google...